# Smokeping rrdtool fetch

Tags: php, perl, parsing, rrdtool

How to fetch data from smokeping rrd file and make output with txt file when host go down or up in perl or php?

I send 10 ICMP packets every 60sec.
I want to fetch data from rrd and parse it to have such output:

> 17 Jun 2015 12:03:00 - host is down
>  17 Jun 2015 12:05:00 - host
>   is up

E.g. host down when no data received or packet loss > 50%

I've already tried:

```
rrdtool fetch /var/lib/smokeping/Host/Swadzim.rrd AVERAGE
 1434546000: -nan 0.0000000000e+00 1.1677527778e-02 9.5520694444e-03 1.0010958333e-02 1.0222916667e-02 1.0669152778e-02 1.1147625000e-02 1.1677527778e-02 1.2782055556e-02 1.3641402778e-02 1.5893805556e-02 2.0290416667e-02 1434546720: -nan 0.0000000000e+00 1.0685083333e-02 9.2544444444e-03 9.5931388889e-03 9.9897500000e-03 1.0258138889e-02 1.0441527778e-02 1.0685083333e-02 1.1117277778e-02 1.1553638889e-02 1.2946375000e-02 1.4254041667e-02
```

Comment: You would be better off not reading it from the `rrd` and instead hooking the upstream `ping` operation instead.

Comment: I've try already:
rrdtool fetch /var/lib/smokeping/Host/Swadzim.rrd AVERAGE<br />
1434546000: -nan 0.0000000000e+00 1.1677527778e-02 9.5520694444e-03 1.0010958333e-02 1.0222916667e-02 1.0669152778e-02 1.1147625000e-02 1.1677527778e-02 1.2782055556e-02 1.3641402778e-02 1.5893805556e-02 2.0290416667e-02
1434546720: -nan 0.0000000000e+00 1.0685083333e-02 9.2544444444e-03 9.5931388889e-03 9.9897500000e-03 1.0258138889e-02 1.0441527778e-02 1.0685083333e-02 1.1117277778e-02 1.1553638889e-02 1.2946375000e-02 1.4254041667e-02

Comment: You could start with some RRD modules in CPAN: https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/rrdpoller/rrdpoller

Comment: Please don't post code in comments. I've pasted your comment into your question.

Answer (score 0):

I think you've a mistaken impression of what `rrdtool` does. It's a very nice tool for collecting time series data, collating it and archiving it. But inevitably - when you *do* archive the data, you lose resolution because you're aggregating your results.

Now, what smokeping does is - ping a server, keeps track of latency and packet loss.

That's all to the good, but if you want to monitor and alarm based on this - what you really need is to do the ping test yourself, rather than reading out of archive logs. At best - you'll be getting out of date information.

You can probably extract the data you need from the rrd. I can't do this for you, because I don't have enough information. What you need to do is:

- Figure out which of the data sources (DS) in your RRD you're interested in.
- Figure out which of the Round-Robin-Archives (RRAs) you want to look at.
- Retrieve the *recent* data for that sample.
- Alert based on it.

`rrdtool fetch` which you refer to - is a step in the right direction. You'll probably need something like:

```
rrdtool fetch filename.rrd AVERAGE -s -5m
```

But then - from the values you get - you'll need to figure out which ones are relevant. (You might want to look at the `LAST` consolidation function as well as that may be relevant).

```
rrdtool info filename.rrd
```

can help you figure this out - it will list the data sources you're logging (in order).

But really - it's just much easier to catch the results of the ping in the first place, rather than ping something, process the data, archive it, consolidate it, and extract a time averaged consolidated result from the archive.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the alerts built into smokeping? They are pretty flexible and can do what you need

https://oss.oetiker.ch/smokeping/doc/smokeping_config.en.html and search for *** Alerts ***

For example

```
*** Alerts ***
to = nettoolsalerts@xxx.com
from = Smokeping@xxx.com

+bigloss
type = loss
# in percent
pattern = ==0%,==0%,==0%,==0%,>0%,>0%,>0%
edgetrigger = yes
comment = suddenly there is packet loss
```